# Jquery to allow negative and positive numbers on text field and negative sign should have 0 indexes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I need to validate a text field to accept only negative or positive numbers and indexing also matters. this is what I have tried so far.

this is HTML code

```
<input type="text" class="negativeaccept" >
```

here is Jquery

```
   $(document).on('keypress','.negativeaccept', function(event) {
   if (((event.which != 46 || (event.which == 46 && $(this).val() == '')) ||
        $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
   }  
   });
```

this code only accepts a positive number with a decimal. I want a negative sign (-) of The 0 indexes.

i try this code and its working `(event.which != 45 || $(this).val().indexOf('-') != -1) &&`
but negative (-)sign enter any index. can you try this better than this a solution.

```js
$(document).on('keypress','.negativeaccept', function(event) {
    if (((event.which != 46 || (event.which == 46 && $(this).val() == '')) ||
            $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which != 45 || $(this).val().indexOf('-') != -1) &&
             (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="negativeaccept">
```

Comment: I'd go with `input` event (works with all ways of entering the value and also in mobile browsers,) and RegExp to validate the value.

Comment: `.indexOf('.') != -1)` means "not not-found".  Use `.indexOf('.') == 0)` to mean "as first character".  You'll need to change the related `&&` to `||` (not all of them)